How can i get the pullrequest approve time?
I use ScriptRunner to connect BitBucket and my BitBucket is Data center.
I wrote a listener for when a pull request is merged, like this
PullRequestMergedEvent pullRequestMergedEvent = event
def pullRequest = pullRequestMergedEvent.getPullRequest()
for (int i = 0 ; i < pullRequest.getReviewers().size() ; i++) {
def getReviewers = pullRequest.getReviewers()
    log.warn("getReviewers=${getReviewers}")
    def getUser = pullRequest.getReviewers().getAt(i).getUser() 
    log.warn("getUser=${getUser}")
    def commitDate = pullRequest.getReviewers().getAt(i).getLastReviewedCommit()
    log.warn("commitDate=${commitDate}")
}

And in the logs it shows me:
pullRequest.getReviewers().size() : 1
getReviewers=[InternalPullRequestParticipant{lastReviewedCommit=a52b5014247ae31d7b10ebc962315d630bb20dfe, role=REVIEWER, status=APPROVED, user=InternalNormalUser{id=3, username=admin}}]
getUser=InternalNormalUser{id=3, username=admin}
lastReviewedCommit=a52b5014247ae31d7b10ebc962315d630bb20dfe

How can I get the date for when that commit (lastReviewedCommit) was created, in "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'" format?

The logs you show do not match the code you show.

@Chaosfire I think they need to get that date first, that's the main problem

@FedericoklezCulloca Seems you are right. But, isn't the question too unfocused in its current format? The formatting part is really a separate question from the main one (and there are god knows how many duplicate targets for date formatting).

We can use the format method with required formatter
Append with below 2 lines
def formattedDate = commitDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
log.warn("formattedDate=${formattedDate}")

Edit If the above solution doesn't work as suggested by a contributor in comment below, then we can invoke command to get commit details in ISO format
git show -s --format=%ci ${commitHash}
to leverage this we can create helper function
def getCommitDate(String commitHash) {
    def command = "git show -s --format=%ci ${commitHash}"
    def process = command.execute()
    process.waitFor()

    if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
        def commitDate = process.in.text.trim()
        return commitDate
    } else {
        log.warn("Error executing git command: ${process.err.text}")
        return null
    }
}

and invoke this method to get commitDate
def commitDate = getCommitDate(lastReviewedCommit)

That wont work as if you look at the Javadoc, commitDate comes from calling getLastReviewedCommit which is actually the hash of the commit, not a date. It doesn't help that the code and output do not line up in the question...
